# updating mysql database with php variable

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update my mysql database, using php using variable method but it is not updating. I don't know what the problem is. This is my code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM total") or die(mysql_error());  
$i=$row['number'];
$n=$i+1;
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE total SET number = " . $n . " WHERE number = " . $i . "") or die(mysql_error());
```

How can I update my mysql database using php?

Comment: Do you get a `mysql_error`?

Comment: DO NOT USE mysql_* libraries, they're old and deprecated. use PDO instead.

Comment: where is `$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)`. Secondly, what is your logic. `select * from total` may return millions of rows, then what benefit will you get with this.

Comment: sorry it is not S it is SET i mistyped when i typed here...

Answer (score 3):

You can increment the column_value like this `column_name = column_name + 1` without using `SELECT`.

```
UPDATE total SET number = number + 1
```

Answer (score 3):

It can be just with SQL without need of select. When it is not required don't use php. What can be done in mysql should be done in mysql. It's faster.

```
UPDATE `total` SET number = number + 1;
```

Moreover, you should read the red box on mysql_* documentation. These functions are depracated and will be removed in future. Consider using **MYSQLI** or **PDO**

Answer (score 2):

your query syntax is wrong, try this,

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE total SET number = '" . $n . "' WHERE number = '" . $i . "'");
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax fo your query is wrong it should be

```
UPDATE `total` SET number = number + 1;
```

you have done

```
UPDATE `total` S number = number + 1;
```

refer this [mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)